# Log4j logging in incorrect file

Tags: log4j

I have a problem with logging in tomcat. 
I use a DailyRollingFileAppender, but the problem is: the file with date log.log.2015-05-25 have data from 2015-05-26... it happens with all files.

This is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.GDebug=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.GDebug.File=/opt/tomcat/logs/log.log
log4j.appender.GDebug.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.GDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.GDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %X{username} %c{1} %m%n
log4j.appender.GDebug.Threshold=DEBUG
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: it's only happened in the server. When I run the app in localhost, it works fine

Comment: Could the problem be related to timezones?

Comment: What version of log4j are you using?  You might be hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-116

Comment: Is this issue resolved for you? I am too facing same issue.